# HTML not reading JavaScript function in <script> tag

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code idk where am wrong pls help!

https://codepen.io/visa2code/pen/oNojdRr

```html
<a class="getstarted" href='javascript:my()'> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-box-arrow-in-right" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
     <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6 3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v9a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-8a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-2a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v2A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 6.5 14h8a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 14.5 2h-8A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 5 3.5v2a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0v-2z" />
     <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M11.854 8.354a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 1 0-.708.708L10.293 7.5H1.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h8.793l-2.147 2.146a.5.5 0 0 0 .708.708l3-3z" />
   </svg></i> &nbsp; &nbsp; Login</a>
```

The thing i placed in script tag

```js
function my() {
      
    Swal.fire({
     icon: 'info',
     title: 'Do you agree to our terms and ads policy?',
     text:'<a href="/terms">Terms</a> and <a href="/ads-policy">Ads Policy</a>,
     footer: 'Copyright 2022 &copy Cryptons API - All right reserved.'
    }).then((result) => {
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
    window.location.href = '/auth/discord/login';
  } else if (result.isDenied) {
   window.location.href = '/';
  }
})
}
```

The error i get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: my is not defined
```

The script tag is placed in the `<head>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
function my() {
      
    Swal.fire({
     icon: 'info',
     title: 'Do you agree to our terms and ads policy?',
     text:'<a href="/terms">Terms</a> and <a href="/ads-policy">Ads Policy</a>',
     footer: 'Copyright 2022 &copy Cryptons API - All right reserved.'
    }).then((result) => {
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
    window.location.href = '/auth/discord/login';
  } else if (result.isDenied) {
   window.location.href = '/';
  }
})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it'll be better if you use onclick for calling functions in
 tags

```
<a class="getstarted" onclick='my()'>
```